# upload file array formData vue

Tags: vue.js, file-upload, vuex

how to make a file upload function in vue js ? here I create a dynamic form that can be added.
I made a form name and uploaded a file

[image]

when the add Attachment button is clicked, the form increases
when I send to the backend, only 1 file is sent, how to make the uploaded file into an array?

and this my code

```
   <div class="col-6">
       <div class="row row g-3" v-for="(attachment, index) in attachment" :key="index">
          <div style="font-size:13px">Attachment</div>
          <div class="col-sm-4">
             <input type="text" v-model="attachment.att_name">
          </div>
          <div class="col-sm-7">
             <div class="col">
                <input type="file" id="file" ref="file" @change="selectFile"/>
             </div>
          </div>
       </div>
       <div style="margin-top: 15px;">
          <button type="button" @click="addNewAttachment">Add Attachment</button>
       </div>
    </div>
    //submit button
    <div style="margin-top:50px">
        <button type="button" @click="onsubmit">Submit</button>
    </div>
```

and this

```
export default {
    name : 'bbb',
     data() {
      return {
        attachment : [
            {
                att_name: '',
                att_file:'',
            }
        ],
      }
    },
    methods:{
        selectFile(e) {
         const selectedFile = e.target.files[0];
         this.attachment.att_file = selectedFile;
        },
        addNewAttachment() {
            this.attachment.push(
                {
                    att_name: '',
                    att_file:'',
                }
            );
        },
        onsubmit(){
            const data = new FormData();
            data.append("item[]", JSON.stringify(this.attachment));
               //for (var lop of data.entries()) {
                  //console.log(lop[1])
               //}
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: What does "make the uploaded file into an array" mean? Do you want to really add the files to an array or did you mean you want to upload multiple files?

Comment: on submit if i console  = attachment [{"att_name":"img1","att_file":{ }},{"att_name":"img 2","att_file":{ }}] 

why the image file doesn't come in ?